# is it possible to configure 6 Monitors with a Amd r7 260x in different graphical virtual consoles?

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, virtual-console

I have a project to configure 6 monitors using eyefinity technology from amd  so i'm figuring out the way to do it, i'm thinking to use tentatively the xfx r7 260x card with 2 dvi ports (DVI-i, DVI-D), 1 HDMI and 1 DP and i'm thinking to connect one monitor to the dvi-i, another one to the dvi-d, one to the hdmi and 3 to the dp using a mst hub, and after that try to open each monitor in different Graphical Virtual consoles so each one will be totally independent.

I [read](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY1MjI) that in kernel 3.16 will be fully working the mst hub, anyway is it possible to put it working with the catalyst drivers? if it's not, probably i could use and Msi AMD Radeon HD 7970 with 4 dp and 2 dvi.

I guess i have to define each monitor in xorg.conf but i'm not sure if it's just that.

I really will appreciate any help.

Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

I have the xfx r7 260x you have.  I have it hooked up to 2 Dell P2815Q (4K), 1 Dell U2713HM (2560x1440) and one Dell E2414Hr (1920x1080) on ubuntu 12.04.  I have the two P2815Q daisy chained on DP, the U2713HM on the DVI-D and the E2414Hr on the DVI-I.  For now, you cannot daisy chain with the open source drivers, but I did manage to get it working with the AMD catalyst driver.  It is not easy and, if you try to boot with all 4 monitors connected, not all of them will work.  I have found this sequence to work most of the time: boot and login with only the two displayport 4K monitors hooked up, then plug in the other two.  Also, this messes up compwiz a little so you may need to mess around with virtual desktops and viewports, and you need to reset any background as it goes black.

David Airlie is working on some MST support (see other questions in this forum) and it is supposed to come in kernel 3.17.  I recently tried 3.17 r7, but it either isn't working, or doesn't work with AMD.  That kernel will not be in ubuntu for a while, so you're best to work with the catalyst drivers for now.

Note: the daisy chain could support the U2713HM (on the end of the chain) too as it has DP imput but, because the two P2815Q need a lot of bandwidth, Displayport 1.2 bandwidth then limits to only two of them working at once.  Displayport 1.3 will increase bandwidth and may allow it to work.

Comment: Last weekend, I moved to ubunto 14.04 (albeit with a new motherboard and bios) and that seems to have solved the quirky startup.  I can now boot with all monitors attached.  I haven't booted that many times yet, so I cannot guarantee it is perfect.  I will add another comment if issues arise.